# comparing strings with file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, string, compare

I am trying to compare a string which is read from a website with only two characters like US, FR, DE, etc with the command below:

```
$country = "http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?;"
$country_content = file_get_contents($country);
$vartest = 'US';
```

and then tried to compare the $country_content which is a string with my input, something like below:

```
if (strcmp($vartest,$country_conent))
    {
    echo 'some text';
    }
```

or

```
if ($country_content == $vartest))
    {
    echo 'some text';
    }
```

and (for any white spaces)

```
if(trim($country_content[0]) == trim($vartest)){
}
```

but I always get the "false" answer for the if statement, I don't know why it is so complicated. I spent so much time on that and now I am supposing it is a bug in PHP. could you shed some light on this?

Comment: It is very unlikely that it is a PHP bug. Is `http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?` the URL you are using? Without parameter? Because I don't see any country code in this page.

Comment: I was trying to hide it for no reason. here's the complete one:
http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=49.03&lng=4

Comment: I got the answer for the file_get_content added white space at the end of the string. trim did not removed it. "rtrim" was the trick